# Inline-div takes too much space

Tags: html, css-float, css

I use foundation for front-end hacking, and basically I want side `div.context` element to take only width available after `div.side` element, but `div.context` gives text inside itself too much space, so it goes away from the strict row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="side left" data-equalizer-watch>
        <span class="bump">&uarr;</span>
        <img src="http://lenta-ua.net/uploads/posts/2014-03/1393873729_apple.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="context left" data-equalizer-watch>
        <h5><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit amet dolor sit amet sit amet amet, LOL here we go some text yeeeah</a></h5>
        <small class="clearfix">submitted 2 minutes ago by <a>tucnak</a></small>
        <div class="info">
            <a href="">0 comments</a>
            <a href="">share</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Hehe]
[image: Hehe]

Yeah, styles!

```
.thread .side {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.thread .context {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the CSS code?

Comment: @DemVoids rest css is nothing about positioning, so I am like 100% sure it won't help ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how ti can be done. It's a similar method smashingmagazine.com uses for their sidebars:

http://jsfiddle.net/C2hcT/

Basically you position one element absolute, and use padding to push the other element out from under it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="side left" data-equalizer-watch> <span class="bump">&uarr;</span>

        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="http://lenta-ua.net/uploads/posts/2014-03/1393873729_apple.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="context left" data-equalizer-watch>
         <h5><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit amet dolor sit amet sit amet amet, LOL here we go some text yeeeah</a></h5>
 <small class="clearfix">submitted 2 minutes ago by <a>tucnak</a></small>

        <div class="info"> <a href="">0 comments</a>
 <a href="">share</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    padding-left:140px;
    position:relative;
}
.thread .side {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.side.left {
    width:120px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:green;
}
.img-wrapper {
    width:100px;
}
.side.left img {
    width:100%;
}
.side.left .bump, .side.left .img-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
}
.thread .context {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but still doesn't looks as a good solution :/

Comment: It's a perfectly viable solution, the only other way would be to set widths on both elements (.side.left) & (.context.left)

Answer (score 0):

I used your html but made some changes to the css and made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/2tZ59/)

Check if this helps you.

I removed `.thread` class name from the css since i didn't find that in the html

```
.side {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left; //Removed this line
}

.context {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left; //Removed this line
}
```

And gave `display:inline-flex;` to the div `.row`